# navigator is not defined when implementing handsontable

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, handsontable

I am using Nuxt Js and trying to implement handsontable. But always facing this issue "navigator is not defined"

Here is the the URl - https://handsontable.com/docs/7.1.1/frameworks-wrapper-for-vue-simple-example.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It means that handsontable isnt ssr compatible. You need to only import and use it on client. See [nuxt faq](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/window-document-undefined/)